# PHP | Array get both value and key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like that:

```
$array = Array
(
    [teamA] => Array
    (
        [188555] => 1
    )
    [teamB] => Array
    (
        [188560] => 0
    )
    [status] => Array
    (
        [0] => on
    )
)
```

In the above example I can use the following code:

```
echo $array[teamA][188555];
```

to get the value 1.

The question now, is there a way to get the 188555 in similar way;

The keys teamA, teamB and status are always the same in the array. Alse both teamA and teamB arrays hold always only one record.

So is there a way to get only the key of the first element of the array teamA and teamB?

Comment: a bit offtopic: I just wanted to say that I think you should use `$array['teamA']` instead of `$array[teamA]` as the latter works just because of a side effect (that undefined constants are treated as strings).. but 1) it generates a notice 2) who knows, maybe sometime you will define a constant `teamA` and you will have big problems in debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo array_keys($array['teamA'])[0];
```

Refer [**`this`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for detailed information from official PHP site.

Answer (score 5):

More simple:

```
echo key($array['teamA']);
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
 foreach($array as $key=>$value)
 {
     foreach($value as $k=>$v)
     {
          echo $k;
      }
 }
```

**OR** use `key`

```
echo key($array['teamA']);
```

Comment: there is no any php function? Just I am asking for any function.

Answer (score 2):

Use two foreach

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

    foreach($value as $key1 => $value2){
        echo $key1;
    }
}
```

This way, you can scale your application for future use also. If there will be more elements then also it would not break application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_flip to exchange keys and values. So array('12345' => 'foo') becomes array('foo' => '12345').

Details about array_flip can be studied [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the simplest way to do this would be to use array_keys()?

So you'd do:

```
$teamAKey = array_shift(array_keys($array['TeamA'])); 
$teamBKey = array_shift(array_keys($array['TeamB']));
```

Obviously your approach would depend on how many times you intend to do it.
More info about [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using list($key, $value) = each($array['teamA']) since the question was for both key and value. You won't be able to get the second or third value of the array without a loop though. You may have to reset the array first if you have changed its iterator in some way.