# get KEY & VALUE from array in PHP?

Tags: php

You can easily get an key from a array but if I have the value, and I have the key,In array And wants boths, whats the best way to get it?

like :

```
$controller = $request->get('_controller');
$home     = array('XXX\ABCBundle\Controller\PageHomeController::indexAction'=>5, 'XXX\ABCBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmedAction'=>10);
```

First time I want key for compression and when this is inter then want to key:-

```
if(in_array($controller,$home)){
       echo "blabla";
   $point = $home[$controller];

}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What you're getting in `$controller` ?

Comment: in $controller current action .

Comment: iterate with a `foreach` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14706992/180100) ?

Comment: @Kunwar Siddharth Singh, @Rikesh Asked about, what is the value of the `$controller` ?

Comment: I don't get it. If you have the key, you already have the key and it's trivial to get a value from an array with it. If you have the value, you already have the value and you can find the corresponding key from an array.

Comment: In this time $controller value is "XXX\ABC\Controller\PageHomeController::indexAction"

Comment: `if (isset($home[$controller]))`...?

Comment: @deceze Why every one get down to my question ? In my case this not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array` searches for a value, but you're looking for a key. You should use `array_key_exists` for this, or `isset($home[$controller])`.

```
if (isset($home[$controller])) {
    echo "blablah";
    $point = $home[$controller];
}
```